# problem involving Fibonacci in arrangement

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, analysis, greedy

The problem statement is as follows: There are N people standing in a row. The ith person is standing in the ith position. In how many ways can we arrange the people so that each person is either in their own position or in their adjacent position?

I figured that
The answer follows the Finonacci pattern.

```
like if N = 1, 
The answer is 1. If N = 2, the answer is 2.
If N = 3, then the answer is 3, if N = 4, then the answer is 5, and so on.

This is via observation. Can you provide concrete proof why this is always true?
```

my attempt:

```
If the (N-1)th number is in its own position, then we can't 
do any change and the answer is just ans[N-1]. Otherwise, 
swap Nth and (N-1)th position and it will give arrangements ans[N-2]
so final ans[N] = ans[N-1]+ans[N-2]
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a practical problem in computer programming. It sounds more like mathematics or computer science - both of which are off-topic on this site.

Comment: of course, it's a programming problem. what do you mean, if I'd write an easy code to find Fibonacci, will it make it a programming problem? Mathematics and algorithm designing is part of programming.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't a programming problem, I said a ***practical problem in computer programming***. This isn't a ***practical problem***. It's off-topic here.

Comment: @Enigmativity This is an algorithms question. While this type of question doesn't always meet some of the site guideline (e.g. about showing code), Algorithms are specifically called out as welcome here: stackoverflow.com/tour. Check out the Algorithms tag for lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction:

As you've shown, your statement is true for small values. Suppose it's true that for every positive integer up to n there are Fib(n) arrangements that meet your criterion. Then, we add a person.

Our new person can occupy two positions: the n'th and (n+1)'st.

In the latter case, we count the Fib(n) ways of arranging the first n items. In the former case it must be that the (n+1)'st and n'th are switched, and there are Fib(n-1) ways of arranging the first n-1 people.

Since Fib(n-1) + Fib(n) = Fib(n+1), we've proved your theorem by induction.